# How to get "apt-get -y upgrade" within a PHP script to function as expected?

Tags: apt, php

Yes, I'm aware of unattended-upgrade, but I don't like that package's limitations.  I've got a PHP script that makes the following calls:

```
...
system("/usr/bin/apt-get update");
system("/usr/bin/apt-get -y upgrade 2>&1 > /tmp/apt_get.txt");
system("/usr/bin/apt-get autoremove");
system("/usr/bin/apt-get autoclean");
...
```

The script is set up via cron to run automatically on a schedule.  It appears to execute all of the commands correctly as root.  However, 'apt-get -y upgrade' doesn't actually perform the upgrade as evidenced here in the output of /tmp/apt_get.txt:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages will be upgraded:
  iproute
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 444 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main iproute amd64 20111117-1ubuntu2.3 [444 kB] Fetched 444 kB in 1s (374 kB/s)
```

Manually running 'apt-get upgrade' shows that the package was downloaded but not installed:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  iproute
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/444 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
Abort.
```

So apt-get successfully downloads the package but doesn't actually perform the upgrade.  What do I need to change to get this script to work as expected?  It almost seems like a bug in "apt-get -y upgrade" itself.  (Running Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS here.)

Answer (score 2):

I assume it asks whether to overwrite/keep/diff edited configuration files.
You need to add DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive in this case.

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y upgrade
```

Comment: Running 'sudo apt-get upgrade' manually (from Bash) didn't ask that for the 'iproute' package.

Comment: Please change the redirection in your code to:
>/tmp/apt_get.txt 2>&1, ordering is important here.

And then add the last lines from /tmp/apt_get.txt again.

Comment: Make the change.  Now the output shows that PATH is not defined.  Added some code to compensate.  I will see if that works.